# Configuring QPalette.Disabled resets other properties like QPalette.Link

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

```py
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, QColor(255, 255, 255))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(255, 255, 255))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, QColor(0, 0, 0))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(195, 60, 240))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, QColor(255, 0, 0))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(255, 255, 255))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(195, 60, 240))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
rootAppPalette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))

rootAppPalette.setColorGroup(QPalette.Disabled, rootAppPalette.windowText(),
                             rootAppPalette.button(), rootAppPalette.light(),
                             rootAppPalette.dark(), rootAppPalette.mid(),
                             rootAppPalette.text(),
                             rootAppPalette.brightText(),
                             rootAppPalette.base(), rootAppPalette.window())
```

QPalette.Link and some other color roles don't reset without `rootAppPalette.setColorGroup(QPalette.Disabled, ...)`, but with this line, some color roles are reset no matter what
Why does it happen and how do I recolor disabled widgets without affecting other color roles?

Comment: Why do you need to use `setColorGroup()` like that? From what I can see, you're not changing anything, and since `setColor()` sets the color fo *all color groups*, there's no point in doing that.

Comment: How do I change QPalette.Disabled without affecting other color roles then?

Comment: I don't understand: in your code you're not changing anything, you're just trying to apply the same colors: using `setColorGroup` is completely pointless if you're using the same colors.

Comment: That's just an example, I will change colors in actual fixed code

Comment: that wasn't clear, you should have pointed out from the beginning. If you only want to specify single colors, just use `setColor(Disabled, <role>, <color>)` (or setBrush) for the colors you want to change, otherwise you'd need to overwrite all the others anyway (see [sources](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qpalette.cpp.html#_ZN8QPalette13setColorGroupENS_10ColorGroupERK6QBrushS3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_)) since Qt automatically sets these roles when using `setColorGroup()`: Shadow, Highlight, HighlightedText, Link, LinkVisited, ToolTipBase, ToolTipText.

Comment: ooh, thank you, sorry for my dumbness, lol